# Android - Change left margin using animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I am changing the left margin of an image view in the following manner :

```java
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams ();
layoutParams.leftMargin = VALUE;
image.setLayoutParams ( layoutParams );
```

I would like the change in margin to apply with animation. Any clues ?

What I tried :

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat ( image , "x" , VALUE);
objectAnimator.start();
```

This works perfectly, as the image is moved to the specified X value with animation, **HOWEVER** the value of **layoutParams.leftMargin** remains unchanged !! So I cannot use this method, because if I try to change the value of **layoutParams.leftMargin** to 100 after using the **objectAnimator** with the value 100, the value applied is not correct ( 200 is applied instead of 100, the effect if the **objectAnimator** remains eventhough I am setting the left margin in the following manner :

```
layoutParams.leftMargin = 100;
```

Comment: See here for a simple solution using ViewPropertyAnimator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33077358/1438339

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Use Animation class, not ObjectAnimator.

```
final int newLeftMargin = <some value>;
Animation a = new Animation() {

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        LayoutParams params = yourView.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin = (int)(newLeftMargin * interpolatedTime);
        yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
};
a.setDuration(500); // in ms
yourView.startAnimation(a);
```

Please note that you should use correct LayoutParams class i.e. if your view is the child of LinearLayout then params should be LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: Don't forget to set the duration, I had some issues with it until I set the duration: `a.setDuration(duration);`

Comment: I get an error when I try to use params.leftMargin . Apparently it's not a field

Comment: It's because there are a lot of LayoutParams classes. For example - ViewGroup.LayoutParams, FrameLayout.LayoutParams, LinearLayout.LayoutParams, etc.
ViewGroup.LayoutParams doesn't have leftMargin field but RelativeLayout.LayoutParams does.

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#Animation(), the default duration is 0ms, so you must set duration as well.

Comment: For packaged Animation implementations and XML resource animations, default duration should be 300ms, right? Anyone have a reference to that?

Comment: You can use android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime. But, I do believe that the value of this variable can differ on different devices or android versions.

Comment: What if I wanted newLeftMargin to be 0 ?

Comment: Also this is not accounting for pixel density

Comment: Magic! replace this to make smoother animation. params.leftMargin = (int) (params.leftMargin + (newLeftMargin - params.leftMargin) * interpolatedTime);

Answer (score 98):

I came by this question, but I couldn't use it because I want to animate the margin from a negative value to 0, so I used valueAnimater base on user1991679 answer:

```
final View animatedView = view.findViewById(R.id.animatedView);
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) animatedView.getLayoutParams();
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(params.bottomMargin, 0);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator)
    {
        params.bottomMargin = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        animatedView.requestLayout();
    }
});
animator.setDuration(300);
animator.start();
```

You must change LinearLayout.LayoutParams according to animatedView container.
Also you can use nineoldandroids for older version that don't have ValueAnimator.

Comment: You can animate the margin from negative to 0 using Animation class. There are no any limitation.

Comment: @user1991679 and how do you animate from say 400 to 200 using the `Animation` class?

Comment: Assume that 200 is newMargin (the margin we should animate to) and 400 is currentMargin (the marging we animete from). In that case the code would look like:

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        LayoutParams params = yourView.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin = currentMargin - (int)((currentMargin - newMargin) * interpolatedTime);
        yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

Comment: I get strange redraws with this. Looks like my layout bobbles a lot.

Comment: @MikeMilla Use it inside a FrameLayout, LinearLayout produces bad effect.

Comment: @Ali I was :/ Ended up using the answer above.

Answer (score 17):

The answer from user1991679 is great, but if you need to interpolate a margin from any other value but 0, you need to use it in your calculations:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) mBottomLayout.getLayoutParams();
final int bottomMarginStart = params.bottomMargin; // your start value
final int bottomMarginEnd = <your value>; // where to animate to
Animation a = new Animation() {
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) mBottomLayout.getLayoutParams();
        // interpolate the proper value
        params.bottomMargin = bottomMarginStart + (int) ((bottomMarginEnd - bottomMarginStart) * interpolatedTime);
        mBottomLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
};
a.setDuration(300);
mBottomLayout.startAnimation(a);
```

In my case I needed to animate an "enter the screen" animation, coming from "-48dp" to 0. Without the start value, the animation is always 0, thus jumping, not animating the view. The solution was to interpolate the offset and add it to the original value.

Comment: I tried this. And while the result is the correct position, it doesn't do the animation anymore. Any idea? If I go back to the non calculated thing the animation works fine..

Comment: You can set a break point when directly after the start point is set, so you can see what is entered. If it jumps, it would mean, that you are assigning the wrong value. In my code snippet, the bottomMarginStart is read from the view, assuming that the view should start the animation where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me like I wanted so...
I needed to create ToggleMenu from -80 dp (oldLeftMargin) to 0dp.
Same with bottomMargin, etc.
Now it works:

```
final int oldLeftMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.left_menu_button_margin_left);
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) llMeniuToggle.getLayoutParams();
            params.leftMargin = oldLeftMargin + (int) ((0 - oldLeftMargin) * interpolatedTime);
            llMeniuToggle.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };
    a.setDuration(500);
    llMeniuToggle.startAnimation(a);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following

```
image.animate().setDuration(durationIn).translationXBy(offsetFloat).start();
```

You can also add `.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator())` to change the look of the animation.