# Change margin with animation on Android

Tags: java, android, animation

I have TableLayout with:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="-60dp"
```

OnCreate I want it to move with animation to marginBottom="0dp"

tried this:
[Android - Change left margin using animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881419/android-change-left-margin-using-animation)

but im getting this error about "Transformation":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXx7y.jpg

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import android.view.animation.Transformation
```