# Android - Animate margin / change position of multiple views at once

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I have a RelativeLayout with 4 Button side by side. On certain event I wish to change position / Change margin of all four Button with animation.

I am currently doing it with following code

```
final RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams params1 = (RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams) button1.getLayoutParams();
final RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams params2 = (RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams) button2.getLayoutParams();
final RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams params3 = (RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams) button3.getLayoutParams();
final RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams params4 = (RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams) button4.getLayoutParams();
final RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams params5 = (RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams) button5.getLayoutParams();

ValueAnimator animator1 = ValueAnimator.ofInt(params1.rightMargin, (deviceWidth - availableWithForTabs + spaceForTabs));
ValueAnimator animator2 = ValueAnimator.ofInt(params2.rightMargin, dpToPx(78));
ValueAnimator animator3 = ValueAnimator.ofInt(params3.rightMargin, dpToPx(52));
ValueAnimator animator4 = ValueAnimator.ofInt(params4.rightMargin, dpToPx(26));
ValueAnimator animator5 = ValueAnimator.ofInt(params5.rightMargin, dpToPx(0));

animator5.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        params5.rightMargin = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
    }
});
animator5.setDuration(150);
animator5.start();

animator4.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        params4.rightMargin = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
    }
);
animator4.setDuration(150);
animator4.start();

animator3.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        params3.rightMargin = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
    }
 });
 animator3.setDuration(150);
 animator3.start();

 animator2.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
     @Override
     public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        params2.rightMargin = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
     }
 });
 animator2.setDuration(150);
 animator2.start();

 animator1.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
 @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        params1.rightMargin = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        button1.requestLayout();
    }
 });
animator1.setDuration(150);
animator1.start();
```

I feel above code is too much to animate margin change for 5 button. Can any one tell me a better way of doing this? or what other options i have? I have to support sdk 16 +

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to rethink your design, using [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) could save you you a lot lines of code and is very readable/maintainable.

Using [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) is pretty simple :

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.animate()
       .translationX(toX)
       .translationY(toY)
       .setDuration(milliseconds);  // add more if you 
                                    // like (alpha, startDelay)                             
                                    // check the docs for available methods
```

The animation always starts at the current position of the View.

For the sake of cleaner code why dont you try something like this :

Write your own Animation Method that takes a View(in your case a Button), and all the values that you need as parameters (minimal implementation of moving a view on the x and y axis) :

```
private void animateView(View view, float toX, float toY, int duration) {
    view.animate()
        .translationX(toX)
        .translationY(toY)
        .setDuration(duration);
}
```

Then you can simply call this method on your buttons to animate them individually f.e. :

```
animateView(button1, 5.0f, 2.5f, 150);
animateView(button2, 2.5f, 1.0f, 150);
```

of course 5.0f, 2.5f etc are only fictional numbers, you'd have to fill in where you want to move the Views yourself.

Extra Suggestion : It is always nice to use Interpolators to make your animation more life like f. e. :

```
view.animate()
    .translationX(...)
    .translationY(...)
    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
    .setDuration(...);
```

If this was not thorough enough or anything is unclear let me know.

UPDATE : 
If you want to set a listener you can either implement the [Animator.AnimatorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html) Interface in your class like this :

```
public class yourClass extends AppCompatActivity implements Animator.AnimatorListener {...
```

Then you are forced to implement the following methods :

```
 @Override
 public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
 // here you can call stuff that should happen when the animation ends,
//     f.e. start the next animation
// the method names explain themselves 
 }
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

}
```

Then all you have to do is add another line to your animateView method :

```
view.animate()
...
...
.setListener(this);
```

Or you can do it in an anonymous inner class like this :

```
view.animate()
...
...
.setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

    }
     // same methods as above ...
    ...
)};
```

Comment: @A Honey Bustard Thanks for your reply. I accept doing it with ViewPropertyAnimator would be lot easier. Is there any way i can add animationEnd Listner with this? and What i need to do if i want to start the 2nd animation only after the first animation finishes. Sorry, If i am asking too much. I am not good with android animation. It would be great to get help

Comment: Thanks a ton. I get this. Would love to know if there are other options other than VIewPropertyAnimator

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just animate the whole relative layout containing the 4 buttons.

Also I suggest to use View.animate method

> public ViewPropertyAnimator animate ()
>
> Added in API level 12
>   This method returns a ViewPropertyAnimator object, which can be used to animate specific properties on this View.
>
> Returns
>   ViewPropertyAnimator The ViewPropertyAnimator associated with this View.